# Follow-up question, how?

Tags: discussion

I like the answer https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/77280/73067 but have a follow-up question. Should rather create a new question than asking the author to elaborate more?

Comment: Can I just compliment you on your excellent taste in answers :-)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should create a new question. It's probably a good idea to include a link to the post that inspired it (but strictly speaking, you don't *have* to).